# Htaccess - mod rewrite "duplicates" my path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wamp, friendly-url

I have spent time wrestling with **.htaccess** and no success at all.

My problem is: I'm working offline with **wamp server** (localhost). My website is in a folder in wamp's main library ( the base url of my website is looks like this: *http://localhost/mydirectoryname*, )

I'm trying to create the .htaccess file to rewrite my nasty urls, but because I'm not familiar with paths/regular expressions it works very strangely.

This is what I have to mask:

> *http://localhost/mydirectoryname/index.php?category=1*

This is what I would like to achieve (at moment)

> *http://localhost/mydirectoryname/categories/1.html*

At first my rewrite works properly ,but after than comes the crazyness. This is what I get (if I keep clicking on my webpage's menu (category) link (a) button more then once)

> http://localhost/mydirectoryname/categories/categories/categories/categories/2.html

My .htaccess file looks like this:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule categories/(.*).html$ index.php?category=$1

---

PS: My final goal is to create this type of url:

> http://localhost/mydirectoryname/categories/1/categoryname.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
RewriteBase /mydirectoryname/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)/index\.php\?category=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/categories/%2.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^categories/(\d+)\.html$ index.php?category=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer , it looks very nice but still doesn't work  =((( (the url now points out to the wamp server mainpage instead of my index.php)

Comment: I guess the htaccess is placed inside the folder `mydirectoryname`? If so, I've updated the code above.

Comment: Thank you again, I really appreciate your help! ( It's still not working for me but this time I think I know what's the problem!  Im pretty sure my Wamp server is  malfunctioning or it's not properly configured, because your code (and my original one) works like a charm in my online test pages.  (Time for me to more googleing - wohoo)